# Centering a navigation bar with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am working on my first website and I am a little confused as to how I would center my navigation bar. I have tried defining a width, made sure it was a block element and set margin-left and margin-right to auto but it still isn't centering. Here are my css and html files.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Misc</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.nav > ul {
    width: 960px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    background: #444444;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.nav li {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
    background: #444444;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid white;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.nav li ul li {
    float: none;
    width: 140px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.nav li:hover {
    background-color: maroon;
}

.nav li:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;

}

.nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.nav li ul {
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: [Courtesy jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s98fC/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s98fC/10/

Answer (score 2):

You're *overriding the definitions* that would've made it centered ...

Change:

```
.nav > ul {
    width: 960px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    background: #444444;
    margin: 0px; /* overrides previously defined margin */
    padding: 0px; /* overrides previously defined margin */
}
```

To:

```
.nav > ul {
    width: 960px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    background: #444444;
    /* margin: 0; */
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what I am doing to override the definitions, would you mind elaborating more so I could avoid doing this in the future?

Comment: This is not quite the same, as now the top ul has the list style ( bullet points ) and it makes the design look sloppy. http://jsfiddle.net/s98fC/3/

Comment: @travisj i'm not trying to make his design *"better"* or any *"less sloppy,"* i'm directly answering his question regarding the centering of the nav menu.

Comment: @Xander - I understand where the confusion is coming from. I downvoted, but I will remove it with an edit. I believe you have a typo in your solution and that `nav > ul ul` was intended to be `nav ul`. As a result of the typo, the affect on nav was noticeable and degraded the content.

Comment: @Xander - It was not? So you intentionally degraded the content. Well you may roll back the edit, but I will also downvote that solution because it changes the OPs original layout in a negative fashion which is not desirable.

Comment: @TravisJ i was specifically pointing out that he was overriding the margin definitions! that's the root problem!!

Comment: I have tried his solution and it turned out okay, however using jsFiddle it seemed to have a different outcome than what I see in my browser.

Comment: @Xander - I think that your assessment was correct for the root problem. But your solution of changing the specificity for the second definition did not work and that was my issue.

Answer (score 0):

change .nav > ul ul to .nav > ul li
and

```
.nav li ul {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    padding-left:0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the width of `.nav>ul` is set more than total width of all nav items inside it. It should be `width: 608px;` and you need to add `margin: 0 auto;` to `.nav ul` rule declaration

**Final rules for `.nav > ul` and `.nav ul`**

```
.nav > ul{
  width: 608px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.nav ul{
  list-style: none;
  background: #444;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: This seemed to do the trick but I was wondering why it had to be 608px, I have tried lower and higher values and it shifted the navigation bar left and right.

Comment: Setting it to `608px` helps because main nav `<ul>` becomes shorter in width than its container and it _can_ be move around horizontally.
The other thing that is necessary to fix your problem is setting `margin:0 auto` for `.nav ul`. See, **all** `<ul>` in your markup including the submenu. However the submenu has no room on left/right so it just stick in its place.
I hope it's understandable now. 
please check my other answer that deals with cascading (the first C in CSS)

Answer (score 0):

Another (and a better) approach is to

1. swap the position of `.nav > ul` and `.nav ul` rule, i.e., specifying the (more specific) `.nav > ul` rule *after* (a relatively generic) `.nav ul`
2. **and** setting `width: 608px;` in `.nav > ul`

This is how it works:

a) `.nav ul` sets the `margin: 0; padding: 0` to all `<ul>` elements. It removes default padding/margin for all `<ul>` elements.

b) Now (assuming, for `.nav > ul`, you don't have left and right margins set to `auto` and `width` is `960px`) you've a left aligned main nav that covers its container horizontally. So, to make it horizontally centered, you set its width to minimun width you can without moving your nav items to new line, i.e., `608px` and set margins to `auto` in order to center it horizontally in its container.

Here's the CSS

```
.nav ul{
   list-style: none;
   background: #444444;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}

.nav > ul{
   width: 608px;
   display: block;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

I hope it helps